# while reading .txt file in java getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/modi/Desktop/hbaseoff/mobiledata.txt")))
        {

            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = sCurrentLine.split("\t");
System.out.println(values[0]+"-"+values[1]+"\t"+values[2]+"\t"+values[3]+"\t"+values[4]);
}

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

output:

```
20150320-9876543217 16  45  22
20150320-8876543218 45  11  13
20150320-8876543219 49  15  16
20150321-9876543210 16  45  22
20150321-9876543211 45  11  13
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>     at Jclass.main(Jclass.java:18)

Comment: check how many tabulators the lines do have. They have to have at least 4 or you get your exception

Comment: To help you with this error, you have to post the file's content. I assume, that the format isn't the same in this row. There my be value[4] missing.

Comment: Check your input data and also debug in while loop. There should be some data which does have required index. Also you can do a length check on Array before printing.

Answer (score 2):

Because there are only 4 tab delimitered values

try

```
System.out.println(values[0]+"-"+values[1]+"\t"+values[2]+"\t"+values[3]);
```

Personally I would put this in a loop

```
for (String val : values) {
   System.out.print (val + "\t");
}
System.out.println ();
```

Comment: my input in file is:

Comment: 20150320 9876543217 16 45 22
20150320 8876543218 45 11 13
20150320 8876543219 49 15 16
20150321 9876543210 16 45 22
20150321 9876543211 45 11 13

Comment: @PrasannModi That is different to what you posted above.  Anyway try using a loop as in my answer.  Could also be caused by a line with blanks on it

Comment: my input is:                                                                               20150320 9876543217 16 45 22
20150320 8876543218 45 11 13
20150320 8876543219 49 15 16
20150321 9876543210 16 45 22
20150321 9876543211 45 11 13
                                                                                                                and output :                                                                               20150320-9876543217 16  45  22
20150320-8876543218 45  11  13
20150320-8876543219 49  15  16
20150321-9876543210 16  45  22
20150321-9876543211 45  11  13

Comment: Looks good then.  If you are still having an error, then maybe due to a blank line

Comment: don't have any blank line

Comment: I am not sure what you are wanting.  I have posted a solution above.  If you are having trouble with that, please ask.  Based upon you above input/output, they seem to be paired, so again what IS the problem?

Comment: in place of while loop what can i use and which condition should i apply

Comment: While loop should be fine, as per your code.  Simply use a for loop to print the values out, as per my code.

Comment: Great to hear, please consider to upvote and/or accept my answer